# Show launch image until webView load

Tags: iphone, ios, webview

How I can show launch image until webView load?

Now when I start my app, I see launch image then 5 second empty screen then google.com site. I want show launch image instead 5 second empty screen. I have Xcode version 4.3.1.

My XViewController.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    [self.webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://google.com"]]];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could add a UIImageView on top of your app's main view, with your launch image in it. When the web page finishes loading, remove the UIImageView.

Answer (score 1):

we are having the delegate methods like

```
- (void)webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
```

go through them they will help u

Comment: Thank you! It work for me. I spent couple hours in documentation and fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code may be helped..

`[NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:3.0];`

// written this code in the App delegate didFinishLaunchingWithOptions.